# Can you attach an Augment Crystal to a Unicorn Horn?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons

Since a Unicorn Horn is specifically named as a +3 Magic Weapon, can a Weapon Augment Crystal be attached to it?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, you can.

Depending on the rank of augment crystals, they can be attached to an object of masterwork quality, enhancement +1 or enhancement +3. Because the unicorn's horn is treated as a magic weapon with enhancement +3, any weapon augment crystal can be attached to it.

Furthermore, it is not specified, that the weapon must be a manufactured weapon, so it should be possible to attach an augment crystal even to natural weapons, as long as they have proper enhancement bonus.

Comment: The only catch is getting natural weapons to be masterwork....